# Clean reinstall of CiviCRM Extension GDPR on Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, extension, gdpr

I've been trying to evaluate the GDPR extension before adopting it fully.  I entered some dummy information about Privacy files, which I now wish to delete and start afresh.  There doesn't seem to be any easy way of deleting that information.  I've tried disabling the extension, uninstalling it and then re-installing it but the information that I originally entered keeps coming back which suggests to me that the information has been stored in the CiviCRM database.

The documentation shows:
Removing¶

```
If you no longer wish to use GDPR, you may disable it, or uninstall it.

    Disable - will turn off GDPR’s features, but preserve any data that you have created with it. If you re-enable GDPR later, you'll be back where you left off.
    Uninstall - can be done after disabling, and will completely remove all traces of GDRP, including the data created with it. If you re-install GDPR later, you'll be back to square one, before you ever installed it.
```

The "removal of all traces" hasn't worked for me and as I've said, I want to do a completely fresh install.
Has anyone else tried to do this and if so, with what results?

Comment: Which privacy details are kept afer uninstalling? If an extension developer states in the documentation that uninstall will remove everyting, you can assume it does. But it stays an assumption. The link below shows the code which runs upon uninstalling: https://github.com/veda-consulting/uk.co.vedaconsulting.gdpr/blob/master/CRM/Gdpr/Upgrader.php#L39

Comment: After uninstalling, the directory at /wp-content/plugins/files/civicrm/ext/uk.co.vedaconsulting.gdpr-2.6 still exists with all its sub-directories.
After re-installing, the GDPR settings in Contacts/GDPR Dashboard/ including Activity types, Point of Contact, and data policy file(current) all return in their original form.

Comment: The uninstall does not remove the directory but it should remove the data from the database. You could probably create an issue on the extension page and if you are in a position you could try to fix it yourself.

Comment: Thanks Jaap for your input on this.  Do you happen to know which tables in the database holds the relevant data?  I'll take a look to see if I can change it.

Comment: It is probably the custom data which doesn't get deleted see https://github.com/veda-consulting/uk.co.vedaconsulting.gdpr/blob/master/xml/CustomData_v1.xml and https://github.com/veda-consulting/uk.co.vedaconsulting.gdpr/blob/master/xml/CustomGroupData.xml but I am not sure where the data exactly gets stored. Another source to check is https://github.com/veda-consulting/uk.co.vedaconsulting.gdpr/blob/master/CRM/Gdpr/Upgrader.php and it could be that some of it are stored as settings.

Comment: We're the extension developers. To confirm, the extension will not remove any of the custom data or activity types when uninstalled, its a deliberate feature as we assume any data collected to date is important and will be required if audited. Hence you'll have to manually disable/remove.

Comment: @parvez saleh Many thanks for your comments.  Could you please tell me in which database tables the data is stored so that I can manually remove.  I don't wish to remove the extension, just to change the data stored ie. the dummy names for the data policy and/or terms and conditions.

Comment: Added an answer (partially based on @ParvezSaleh comment.)

Answer (score 1):

**Taken from a comment by [@ParvezSaleh](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/users/271/parvez-saleh)**

The extension does not remove the custom data or activity types when uninstalled. This is a deliberate feature as it's assumed that any data collected to date is important and would be required if an audit takes place.

It would therefore be necessary to manually remove the information from the database.

The extension's settings are stored in the `civicrm_settings` database table as a record with `name` set to `gdpr_settings`.

Other information (activities, custom field data) are stored in various database locations including `civicrm_activity` and `civicrm_value_sla_acceptance_N` (there may be other locations.)